# Integrating .html extensions with VideoJS?

Tags: javascript, php, html, video

So i'm using the VideoJS HTML5 video player

on my *in progress* video streaming website.

The problem i've encountered is that the player has no problem playing links that end in the 
(.MP4) extension. But the way my site functions is it acts as a video aggregator
by pulling links from various websites, the websites are similar to **[this one](http://allmyvideos.net/embed-bpaveh5vsc8k-600x360.html)**

taking that website link for example >
Notice how it ends with the .html extension and when you go to it, it has it's own unique video player, what I want to do is to be able to play that video in video js.
My aggregator saves links to the videos (.html , .php) and not the actual video file itself, is there a way of achieving this? or is it impossible? thanks!